# Rails dependent destroy and really destroy an acts_aS_paranoid object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have two models articles and bookmarks. Both are defined as acts_as_paranoid objects. Relationship between them is

article.rb

```
  has_many :bookmarks, foreign_key: 'article_doi', primary_key: 'doi', dependent: :destroy
```

bookmark.rb

```
  belongs_to :article, foreign_key: 'article_doi', primary_key: 'doi'
```

Now I want to really remove a bookmark object and also remove the dependent bookmarks objects.

```
@article.destroy!
```

and checked

```
@article.bookmarks
```

did not remove the article or its bookmarks. How can I really remove them from the database and its associated bookmarks?

Comment: Are `@article` and `@articles` same objects? What was the result of `@article.destroy!` ?

Comment: check my edited question

Comment: If you need to remove completely from your db, why do you have acts_as_paranoid?

Comment: remove from db not in all cases. At some time I will remove, sometime I will completely remove from DB

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To permanently destroy from database you can use `really_destroy!` method.
Try using `@article.really_destroy!`

https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia#usage

Comment: Will it also destroy its associations properly?

Comment: Yes. If you have `dependent: destroy` in associations.

Comment: Not sure if my question was clear, let me ask again. Will it actually hard delete its associations? Also i have callback with simple deletes on some records, will that also be hard deleted or not. thanks for the help

Comment: Yes, all associated records will be hard deleted.